# Is there a way in TypeScript to use an interface as a guard without losing the specificity of the object?

Tags: typescript, types, interface

I have a problem where I am trying to make an interface for shared modules in TypeScript that for the purpose of this question let's assume has the following shape:

```js
interface A {
  x: string;
  y: { [name: string]: (...args: any) => {type: string; payload?: any} };
  z?: () => any
}
```

The purpose of this interface is two-fold:

1. For the person producing the module, I want them to be able to know that the thing they are creating complies to A.
2. For the person consuming the module, I want them to be able to have the most specific typing possible.

---

For example, if I had:

```js
const bar = {
  x: 'hello',
  y: { 'world': (a: string, b: number) => ({ type: a, payload: b}) }
}
```

Note the lack of reference to interface `A`.

If I were to then type: `bar.` I would get intellisense that it has properties `x` and `y`. Even more though, upon typing `bar.y.` I would get prompted that `world` exists and the function type associated with it.

However, if I add in `A`:

```js
const bar: A = {
  x: 'hello',
  y: { 'world': (a: string, b: number) => ({ type: a, payload: b}) }
}
```

it helps the case of someone accidentally adding a wrong property like:

```js
const bar: A = {
  iDontBelong: true, // wrong
  x: 'hello',
  y: { 'world': (a: string, b: number) => ({ type: a, payload: b}) }
}
```

or even

```js
const bar: A = {
  x: 5, // wrong
  y: { 'world': (a: string, b: number) => ({ type: a, payload: b}) }
}
```

The problem is now if someone were to import `bar` and type `bar.` they would get suggestions that are directly for interface `A`. It loses the knowledge that `bar` only has `x` and `y` (and no `z`), and it also loses the information about `y`'s specific type meaning it wouldn't even know `world` existed on `y`.

Is there any way to get both of these things to exist at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to get both of these things to exist at the same time

As soon as you say `: A` then you will *not* get intellisense for things in the object bag (`[name: string]`).

You can avoid this by not *annotating* but doing a type test e.g.:

```
const bar = {
  x: 'hello',
  y: { 'world': (a: string, b: number) => ({ type: a, payload: b}) }
}
const _ensureA: A = bar; // Type test
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of your approach, however, I found that this doesn't seem to prevent adding `iDontBelong` to `bar`. :(

Comment: I believe this is due to the fact that `bar` is a variable instead of an object literal. 
"Object literals get special treatment and undergo excess property checking when assigning them to other variables, or passing them as arguments. If an object literal has any properties that the “target type” doesn’t have, you’ll get an error."